# apply if statement item within array loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, if-statement

Amateur coder here so I appreciate clear instructions if possible!

I have a script that takes a large XML output from an API, iterates over the arrays, and then outputs using this code

```
// iterate over people
foreach (array_keys($people) as $p) {
    print("person : " . $p . "\n");

    // iterate over dates
    foreach(array_keys($dates) as $d) {
        print("    date : " . $d . "\n");

        // iterate over sessions
        foreach($sessions as $s) {
            $key = sprintf("%s:%s:%s", $p, $d, $s);
            // print if person is working at this person:date:session
            if (array_key_exists($key, $person_date_session)) {
                printf("        session %s : location %s\n", $s, $person_date_session[$key]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is that it outputs the data for every person in $people. I want to output the data (session and location) only for one person in $people. What can i write to do this, and where do i place the code?

Thank you in advance

Comment: How do you know which person you want to output info from?

Comment: this is one line of the output (this is repeated for every person)

"person : Billy Qureshi date : 2020-04-02 session am : location Leazes 9 session pm : location Leazes 9"

Comment: i will manually enter the value of the name into the code. it will be the same each time i run the code so it doesnt need to change each time.

Comment: Well if you cannot pass that to the API so it only gives you that one persons info. Then you have to add an IF after the first loop like `if ( ! $p == 'Billy' ){ continue;}`

Comment: ill give it a try! thank you

Comment: it works without the ! - so thank you very much!